Pan, orbit, zoom camera in Fusion 360 api
I get 6 numbers from a 3D mouse.
(x, y, z, yaw, roll, pitch)
How do I change the camera coordinates in the python fusion 360 api in order to do pan, orbit, zoom operations?
My code addin python code bellow:
-----------------------
\
python
import adsk.core, adsk.fusion, traceback, math, time 

import os, sys  

from . import commands 

from .lib import fusion360utils as futil 

 

install\_ = sys.path\[0\] +'\\Python\\python.exe -m pip install pyserial'  

os.system('cmd /c "' + install\_ + '"')  

 

import serial 

ser = serial.Serial('COM8', 9600) 

def move_camera(app, view):  

    while(True): 

        try:  

            camera = view.camera  

             

            target = camera.target  # Use current camera target  

            up = adsk.core.Vector3D.create(0, 1, 0)  

            data = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip().split(' ')  

            if len(data) == 6:

                \# x y z yaw pitch roll 

                dist = camera.target.distanceTo(camera.eye) 

                start_eye = camera.eye  

                \# Pan  

                new_target = adsk.core.Point3D.create(target.x, target.y, target.z)  

                camera.target = new_target  

     

                \# Orbit  

                new_eye = adsk.core.Point3D.create(dist \* math.cos((math.pi\*2) \* data\[3\]), dist \* math.sin((math.pi\*2) \* data\[4\]), dist \* math.sin((math.pi\*2) \* data\[5\])) 

                camera.eye = new_eye  

 

                #zoom 

                zoom_factor = float(data\[0\]) 

                new_target = adsk.core.Point3D.create(target.x \* zoom_factor, target.y \* zoom_factor, target.z \* zoom_factor) 

                camera.target = new_target 

 

                camera.upVector = up  

                camera.isSmoothTransition = True  

                view.camera = camera  

            else: 

                break 

            adsk.doEvents()  

            view.refresh()  

            time.sleep(0.005)  

                     

        except:  

            ui = app.userInterface  

            if ui:  

                ui.messageBox('Failed:\\n{}'.format(traceback.format_exc())) 

                stop() 

 

 

 

def run(context): 

    try: 

        \# This will run the start function in each of your commands as defined in commands/\__init_\_.py 

        commands.start() 

        main() 

    except: 

        futil.handle_error('run') 

 

 

def stop(context): 

    try: 

        \# Remove all of the event handlers your app has created 

        futil.clear_handlers() 

        commands.stop() 

 

    except: 

        futil.handle_error('stop') 

 

 

def main(): 

    ui = None 

   

    try: 

        app = adsk.core.Application.get() 

        move_camera(app, app.activeViewport) 

     

    except: 

        ui = app.userInterface 

        if ui: 

            ui.messageBox('Failed:\\n{}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))

